# AsyncTask executing once (when the application is launched only)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I don't really know if this an AsyncTask problem, but for what I've seen it seems there's something im missing about this class.

I have the following code:

```
package com.example.webserviceejemplo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ActividadPrincipal extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_principal);

        // Objectos de la vista
        final TextView txtvFeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvFeed);
        final EditText txtXMLUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtXMLUrl);
        final Button btnMostrarXML = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMostrarXML);

        // Scroll vertical (mas una propiedad en el XML)
        txtvFeed.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        btnMostrarXML.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                new XMLHandler().execute(txtXMLUrl.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private class XMLHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            String xml = null;
            try 
            {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return xml;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {  
            setContentView(R.layout.actividad_principal);
            TextView txtvFeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvFeed);
            txtvFeed.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/url_to_show"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtXMLUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textUri" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMostrarXML"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/show_xml" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtvFeed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/feed_to_display" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is to click the button and display the content of the remote XML (yes without parsing it) in the TextView called "txtvFeed". Now, the problem is all works fine, but just the first time you do it, I mean it works only once, when you launch the application. Then if you enter another feed url in the EditText and click the button it won't display that feed's content. In fact I have no idea what is doing after displaying the content, because I get no messages at all.

I literally have no clue about what's the problem. I only have 1 layout and 1 .java, just for you to know.

Any help is welcome as im new at Android :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the setcontentview in postexecute in asynctask class and declare and define the textview in only once, you have used in twice. initalize the textview in globally,

```
TextView txtvFeed;  //globally

txtvFeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvFeed);
```

change the postexecute like this,

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{  
    txtvFeed.setText(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It should work..

```
public class ActividadPrincipal extends Activity 
{
    final TextView txtvFeed;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_principal);

    // Objectos de la vista
    txtvFeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvFeed);
    final EditText txtXMLUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtXMLUrl);
    final Button btnMostrarXML = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMostrarXML);

    // Scroll vertical (mas una propiedad en el XML)
    txtvFeed.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    btnMostrarXML.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            new XMLHandler().execute(txtXMLUrl.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

private class XMLHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        String xml = null;
        try 
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {  
        txtvFeed.setText(result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's almost the same answer as above so I'll upvote it, but making it final outside the onCreate function doesn't allow you to change it after :P.